# Derivative of OPEs in conformal field theory

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory

Suppose you have the following OPE of a free theory:

$$\partial X(z)\partial X(w) = \frac{\alpha'}{2}\frac{1}{(z-w)^2}+...$$

Then $X(z) \partial^2X(w)$ is given by

$$X(z) \partial^2X(w) = +\frac{\alpha'}{2(z-w)^2}$$

I'm having trouble understanding how is this obtained. Do we just take the derivative of of the first expression wrt $w$ and then "integrate" wrt $z$? If so why is there not a minus sign in from of this expression?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the free boson field, $X$, has a logarithmic singularity in its OPE (see Polchinski 2.2.4)
$$
 X(z) X(w)  = -\frac{\alpha'}{2} \log |z-w|^2 + \text{normal ordered terms}~.
$$
Now taking one derivative each wrt $z$ and $w$ gives
$$
\partial_z X(z)\partial_w X(w) = \frac{\alpha'}{2}\frac{1}{(z-w)^2}+...~,
$$
while taking two derivatives wrt $w$ gives
$$
 X(z)\partial_w^2 X(w) = \frac{\alpha'}{2}\frac{1}{(z-w)^2}+...~.
$$
In both cases, the overall sign is +.